# Polymer this-pointer

Tags: javascript, this, polymer, this-pointer

I'm using the Polymer framework and I really enjoy it. But one thing I don't get is the confusion with the this-pointer. When functions get called from for example a button in your custom component the this-pointer points to the custom component. Very logical. But when your function within a custom component is called from something external, for example a callback from an library or a call from another component the this-pointer is something totally different. Why is it in this case not pointing to the custom component where the function is in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is a bit of a weird bird when it comes to resolving [`this`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/operators/this), often not doing what you would like. The only saving grace is that it's easy to explain and understand.

A function's `this` value is set by how it is called. Suppose you have a value `val` with a method `method`. If method is called like `val.method()` then in that call to `method` then `this` is `val`. If you instead do `var theMethod = val.method; theMethod();` then for that call, `this` is something else (the global context object, in browsers this is `window`).

The solution fortunately is simple. There's a method on functions called [`bind`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/function/bind) that returns a new function that has the `this` immutably baked in. So `var theMethod = val.method.bind(val); theMethod()` has `this` bound to `val`.

In the future for many cases we'll be able to use [ES6 Arrow Notation](http://devdocs.io/javascript/functions/arrow_functions) to get this behavior baked in at function definition time, but for now, when passing a method around (e.g. to register an event handler) be sure to bake the `this` in explicitly with `bind`.

Comment: This is exactly the answer that I needed. It requires some extra code, but the this-pointer is what I expect it to be. Thanks a lot for the extended explanation.